# Ruby while loop with sleep

Tags: ruby, loops, sleep

Given the following ruby:

```
$i = 0
$num = 3

while $i < $num  do
    puts "My loop just executed"
    sleep 10
    $i +=1
end
```

I would expect that every 10 seconds (plus execution time) I would get "My loop just executed" printed to my console until $i = 3

```
My loop just executed
# sleeps for 10 seconds
My loop just executed
# sleeps for 10 seconds
My loop just executed
# sleeps for 10 seconds
```

However what actually happens is the script runs, nothing is printed to console until $i = 3 and then i get 3 lines printed at once:

```
My loop just executed
My loop just executed
My loop just executed
```

I can't understand why it wont print after each loop as oppose to printing all at the end?

Why is this and how can I get it to work as I am expecting it to? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It looks to me that you will need a separated thread to achieve what you want. A worker and a main function.

Comment: Where are you incrementing your while loop?

Comment: its just a dummy example but i will update for clarity @leok

Comment: Look into Threads as @SnakeSanders said

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The console output is buffered and nobody promised to [`IO#flush`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-flush) it for you:

```
$i = 0
$num = 3

while $i < $num  do
    $stdout.puts "My loop just executed"
    $stdout.flush
    sleep 10
    $i +=1
end
```

Comment: so in simple terms ruby isn't refreshing the output until it finishes? In your solution im forcing a refresh on each loop with the .flush?

Comment: `ruby` has nothing to do with standard output settings. It’s up to console to decide when the buffer is to be flushed (unless flushed explicitly, as in my example.) On my Linux box it flashes immediately on every call to `puts`.

Answer (score 10):

Ruby automatically flushes output if stdout is a terminal device (tty) and buffers the output if it is not.

For example, running this from a terminal will usually output "hello" immediately:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts "hello" ; sleep 5 ; puts "world"'
hello
# 5 seconds delay
world
$
```

Because of:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts $stdout.tty?'
true
```

Whereas piping the output to another command will usually delay (i.e. buffer) the output until the script has finished:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts "hello" ; sleep 5 ; puts "world"' | cat
# 5 seconds delay
hello
world
$
```

Because of:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts $stdout.tty?' | cat
false
```

To immediately flush any output regardless of whether stdout is a tty, you can set `$stdout`'s [`sync`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D) to `true` at the beginning of your script:

```
$stdout.sync = true
```

Applied to the above example:

```
$ ruby -e '$stdout.sync = true ; puts "hello" ; sleep 5 ; puts "world"' | cat
hello
# 5 seconds delay
world
$
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really useful!